# Campaign cost (total spend) from Twitter Ads API

Tags: python, twitter, ads-api

I am trying to pull campaign costs/total spend from the API
I am 100% new to the API and I am not able to crack it through

I want to :
1- get cost per campaign
2- get campaign ids that showup on the GUI not just the kind of weird codes ie 8cdfn vs 1448530943

here is my python code so far

```
    from twitter_ads.client import Client
    from twitter_ads.cursor import Cursor
    from twitter_ads.http import Request
    from twitter_ads.error import Error
    import time
    from twitter_ads.campaign import LineItem
    from twitter_ads.enum import METRIC_GROUP
    from twitter_ads.enum import GRANULARITY
    client = Client(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
    account = client.accounts(ACCOUNT_ID)
    cids = map(lambda x: x.id, account.campaigns())
    resource = ‘/2/stats/accounts/{account_id}/’.format(account_id=account.id)
    params = { ‘entity’:‘CAMPAIGN’,
    ‘entity_ids’:cids,
    ‘start_time’: ‘2017-12-10’,
    ‘end_time’:‘2017-12-16’,
    ‘granularity’:‘TOTAL’,
    ‘metric_groups’: ‘BILLING’,
    ‘placement’: ‘PUBLISHER_NETWORK’}

    try, build and execute the request with error handling
    try:
    response = Request(client, ‘get’, resource, params=params).perform()
    print(response.body[‘data’])
    except Error as e:
    # see twitter_ads.error for more details
    print e.details
    raise
```

Comment: for the campaign Id part .. campaigns are simply base 36 so 
int('8cdfn',36) will fix that

Comment: Hey Hussein, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @user2407147 yes I did. The trick is to loop over placements because passing multiple placements in a single call doesn't actually work

Comment: what is the difference between `twitter-ads` ,`twitter-api`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that worked for me
the trick is that passing multiple placements doesn't work in the API

```
from datetime import date,timedelta
import datetime
import logging
import sys
import os
import gzip
import shutil
import csv
import requests
import json
from twitter_ads.client import Client
from twitter_ads.cursor import Cursor
from twitter_ads.http import Request
from twitter_ads.error import Error
from twitter_ads.client import Client
from twitter_ads.campaign import LineItem
from twitter_ads.enum import METRIC_GROUP
from twitter_ads.enum import GRANULARITY
import twitter_ads
import time
client = Client(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)



# load the advertiser account instance
  account = client.accounts(ACCOUNT_ID)
  cids = list(map(lambda x: x.id.encode('utf-8'), account.campaigns()))
  campaigns = list(map(lambda x: [x.id.encode('utf-8'),x.name.encode('utf-8'), int(x.id,36)] , account.campaigns()))
  resource = '/2/stats/accounts/{account_id}/'.format(account_id=account.id)
  spend=[]
  for c in campaigns:
    for p in ['ALL_ON_TWITTER', 'PUBLISHER_NETWORK']:
      params = { 'entity':'CAMPAIGN',
  'entity_ids':c[0], #cids,
  'start_time': target_date,
  'end_time':target_date+timedelta(1),
  'granularity':'DAY',
  'metric_groups': ['BILLING','ENGAGEMENT'],
         'placement': p
           }

# try, build and execute the request with error handling
      try:
        req =Request(client, 'get', resource, params=params)
        response = req.perform()
        val = response.body['data']
        val.append(p)
        val.append(c[0])
        val.append(c[1])
        val.append(c[2])
        spend.append(val)
      except Error as e:
        # see twitter_ads.error for more details
        print e.details
        raise
  ddd= json.loads(json.dumps(spend))
  with open(target_path+row['account_id']+'_campaign_spend.csv', "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerow(['time_id','campaign_id_36', 'campaign_id','campaign_desc','placement','spend_micro', 'account_id'])
    for val in ddd:
        if (val[0]["id_data"][0]["metrics"]['billed_charge_local_micro'] and val[0]["id_data"][0]["metrics"]['billed_charge_local_micro'][0]):
          writer.writerow([str(target_date).replace("/","-"),val[2],val[4],val[3],val[1], val[0]["id_data"][0]["metrics"]['billed_charge_local_micro'][0], ACCOUNT_ID])
```

Comment: Is the field `billed_charge_local_micro` the cost amount of the day? It isn't clear to me.

Comment: Yes, this is the spend but the aggregation is per day/per other dimensions you have in your API query 
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/ads/analytics/overview/metrics-and-segmentation

Answer (score 0):

I used much of what you initially wrote for a recent requirement of my own.  This is what I came up with:

```
from twitter_ads.client import Client
from twitter_ads.enum import ENTITY, GRANULARITY, METRIC_GROUP, PLACEMENT
from twitter_ads.http import Request
from twitter_ads.error import Error
from datetime import date, timedelta


CONSUMER_KEY = "CONSUMER_KEY"
CONSUMER_SECRET = "CONSUMER_SECRET"
ACCESS_TOKEN = "ACCESS_TOKEN"
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = "ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET"
ACCOUNT_ID = "ACCOUNT_ID"

client = Client(consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY,
                consumer_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET,
                access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN,
                access_token_secret=ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

# For yesterday's total spend - for other date ranges you'll naturally need to
# update these two variables
time_offset = "T00:00:00-04:00"
yesterday = (date.today() - timedelta(1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + time_offset
today = str(date.today()) + time_offset

# Could be done in a campaign loop as well ...
# account = client.accounts(id=ACCOUNT_ID)
# for camp in account.campaigns():
    # print(str(camp.id) + ": " + camp.name)

resource = f"/7/stats/accounts/{ACCOUNT_ID}/"

params = {
  "entity": ENTITY.CAMPAIGN,
  "entity_ids": "CAMPAIGN ID HERE",
  "start_time": yesterday,
  "end_time": today,
  "granularity": GRANULARITY.TOTAL,
  "metric_groups": METRIC_GROUP.BILLING,
  "placement": PLACEMENT.ALL_ON_TWITTER
}

try:
    req = Request(client=client,
                  method="GET",
                  resource=resource,
                  params=params)

    response = req.perform()

    # Total spend in "micros"; for USD, $37.50 is represented as 37500000
    spend_in_micros = response.body["data"][0]["id_data"][0]["metrics"]["billed_charge_local_micro"][0]

    spend = round((spend_in_micros / 1000000), 2)

    print(spend)

except Error as e:
    print(e.details)
    raise
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I was a contributor to [pywindsorai](https://github.com/windsor-ai/pywindsorai).

Assuming you just need the clicks (or spend) data, you can do this using [windsor.ai](http://www.windsor.ai/) as well, which is a bit simpler to use. You just have to connect your Twitter account to windsor.ai, and then use their Python SDK ([pywindsorai](https://github.com/windsor-ai/pywindsorai)) to load the data into pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
 
from pywindsorai.client import Client
from pywindsorai.enums import LAST_7D
from pywindsorai.enums import FIELD_SOURCE, FIELD_CAMPAIGN, FIELD_CLICKS
 
api_key = 'xxx'  # Get this from your windsor.ai account
 
client = Client(api_key)
campaign_clicks = client.connectors(date_preset=LAST_7D, fields=[FIELD_SOURCE, FIELD_CAMPAIGN, FIELD_CLICKS])

df = pd.DataFrame(campaign_clicks['data'])
```

Comment: please specify if you're affiliated to windsor software or not.

Comment: Please add disclosure to *all* your answers where you link to the product you're affiliated with.

Answer (score 0):

Im triying to get the same but I cant make it.
I follow all the solution proposed but I received an answer which is the following:
`    req =Request(Client, 'get', resource, params=params)

```
 response =req.perform() 
 val = response.body['data']
 val.append(p)  
 val.append(c[0])`
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31096323)